# How to animate MKMapView which is located in parentView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, mkmapview

all I want to do is to change region of map view which is located in main view while the child view controller is displayed. 
As you can see I'm displaying child view controllers on half of the screen by implementation of`UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate` and then I'm displaying details view controller when row is selected by the user.

[image]

I know how to animate region by using the following method:

```
    [mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
```

I'm wondering if I can send value of region from child view to main view controller and update map view region when users list view controller is still on top.

Comment: If I understand correctly, have you tried `[UIView animateWithDuration:]`?

Comment: Set main view controller as a delegate of child view controller and then when select a row let delegate know you select it and pass the region?

Comment: This is just a question about how to communicate between view controllers (not really an MKMapView question).  There are several ways to do it but try one of these two: protocol+delegate or notifications.